# Edit user columns not using the edit action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic

Using Rails 3.1 and authlogic. I have a User model, where I want to separate the forms to several parts, so that I don't mix the profile, account settings, change password in one form. These columns are all in the same table.

Problem with this is that whenever it doesn't pass the validation on either of the action, I could only return a flash error message. I want to use the normal error messages to be embedded on the same action, but because I am using `redirect_to :back`, I can't store any error messages.

What should I do to use the Rails error messages the native way?

Here are my code:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "Welcome!"
      redirect_back_or_default account_url
    else
      render :action => :new
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = @current_user
    @header_title = 'Account settings'
  end

  def edit
    @user = @current_user
  end

  def update
    @user = @current_user # makes our views "cleaner" and more consistent
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:notice] = "Account settings updated."
      redirect_to :back
    else
      flash[:error] = "Errors found. Please check again."      
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end

  def password
    @user = @current_user
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Because error messages are stored on instance variables, and those instance variables won't be around for the GET request the user's browser will make after a redirect, you should instead render the template you wish to take them back to from the update action.

Since you have different sections that can possibly PUT to update, you might inspect the referer within the update action in order to decide which template to render.

Alternatively (and perhaps, more cleanly), you could create new resources for these different sections. Thinking of names may be difficult, but that would allow you to separate concerns and potentially write less code.